# How to compare a node's atrribute with all preceding siblings' attributes in xslt 1.0? (without keys)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML-file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<goods>
    <item class="fruit">apple</item>
    <item class="fruit">pineapple</item>
    <item class="vegetables">tomato</item>
    <item class="fruit">lemon</item>
    <item class="fruit">melon</item>
    <item class="fruit">orange</item>
    <item class="vegetables">cucumber</item>
    <item class="vegetables">onion</item>
    <item class="vegetables">garlic</item>
</goods>
```

I need to get from it (but without using keys or Muenchian method) XML like this:

```
<fruit>
    <item class="fruit">apple</item>
    <item class="fruit">lemon</item>
    <item class="fruit">melon</item>
    <item class="fruit">orange</item>
    <item class="fruit">pineapple</item>
</fruit>
<vegetables>
    <item class="vegetables">cucumber</item>
    <item class="vegetables">garlic</item>
    <item class="vegetables">onion</item>
    <item class="vegetables">tomato</item>
</vegetables>
```

As you can see I need to group the items according to their class attribute (and as an extra to sort them in alphabetical order but this is not neccesary now).

My XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
            <xsl:sort select="@class"/>
            <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="p" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="./@class != ./preceding-sibling::*[1]/@class">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@class"/>

        <xsl:element name="{$id}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[@class = $id]">
                <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, with this code I don't get the expected result. 
What I don't undestand is how to compare a node's attribute with the atrributes of all the preceding siblings. I tried to do it like this:

```
<xsl:if test="./@class != ./preceding-sibling::*/@class">
```

but it didn't work. So i tried this way:

```
<xsl:if test="./@class != ./preceding-sibling::*[1]/@class">
```

but of course it compares only with the previous sibling so this is not the correct code either.

Maybe someone could help me with this? Any help would be appreciated.

A huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is that you say "but without using keys or Muenchian method"?

Comment: I have great difficulty with questions that say "I need to do X, but with one hand tied behind my back". Why the restriction on how you achieve the result?

Comment: @Martin Honnen, thank you for your attention. I was forbidden to use keys and Muenchian method by my teacher at the XSLT courses. So, had to ask here...

Comment: @Michael Kay, thank you for your attention. The restriction comes from my teacher at the XSLT courses. And as I'm new to XSLT I didn't know how to make my code work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you won't use keys or the Muenchian method, but if you must, you could do this simply (albeit inefficiently!) by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/goods">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="item[not(@class = preceding-sibling::item/@class)]">
            <xsl:sort select="@class"/>
            <xsl:element name="{@class}">
                <xsl:for-each select="../item[@class = current()/@class]">
                    <xsl:sort/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this depends on the values of the `class` attribute being valid element names.

---

> if it will not bother you could you also explain 2 Xpath expressions
>   you used: 'item[not(@class = preceding-sibling::item/@class)]' and
>   '../item[@class = current()/@class]'.

```
item[not(@class = preceding-sibling::item/@class)]
```

selects any `item` whose `class` is different from any preceding `item` - thus only **distinct items** are selected. I am rather surprised you're asking about that, since it does exactly what it says in your question's title.

```
../item[@class = current()/@class]
```

selects any `item` whose `class` is equal to the current one - thus all **items in the current group** are selected.

See also: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html where this method is explained alongside the more efficient Muenchian method.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! But if it will not bother you could you also explain 2 Xpath expressions you used: 'item[not(@class = preceding-sibling::item/@class)]'   and   '../item[@class = current()/@class]'.  Thank you in advance!